# ASP.NET Core SPA Vue Template vs Vue CLI

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, vue-cli

I'm starting to learn about Single Page Aplications (SPA) and I was left with several doubts, although I searched a lot.

Let's consider a SPA application with Vue and a **Web API** application (ASP.NET Core), both on **different** servers.

**1. Why would I use an ASP.NET Core Vue template if I can generate a pure Vue project with Vue CLI??**

**2. Is there any advantage in using the client made from an ASP.NET Core Vue template on the purely Vue client? The same goes for React and Angular?**

Comment: google should be an better tool instead of ask at here. below is [one of the results](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-exactly-is-client-side-rendering-and-hows-it-different-from-server-side-rendering-bd5c786b340d) by keyword= **server render vs client render**

Comment: hi  Sphinx, my doubt was about when to use these template types, MS ASP.NET or pure Vue, I could not find anything on google about, maybe because I was newbie to the subject and did not know how to use the correct terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "on different servers" you mean that the Vue application is hosted on a different server than your API, then I don't believe there is any advantage that you'd have by using the Visual Studio templates.  The templates are designed to contain the two projects (client-side and API) into one, so that the development and deployment of both can be done together.

So if you're planning on deploying your .NET API and Vue application to different servers, then you'd probably leave the SPA configuration out of your .NET app, hence no need for the template.

Comment: Hello K. Akins You gave me a light on it, that's exactly what I was wondering, thanks!